# Karnaugh-Veitch Map.

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science, boolean-algebra

Reduce $F(X,Y,Z,W) = \sum (0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,15)$ using Karnaugh-Veitch map.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline_{xy}\backslash^{wz}
 & \overline Z \overline W \quad\scriptsize{00}& \overline Z W \quad\scriptsize{01}& ZW \quad\scriptsize{11}& Z\overline W \quad\scriptsize{10}\\ \hline
\overline X \overline Y\quad\scriptsize{00}& 1 \qquad\scriptsize0& 1\qquad\scriptsize1 & 0\qquad\scriptsize3 &0 \qquad\scriptsize2 \\ \hline
\overline X Y\quad\scriptsize{01}&1 \qquad\scriptsize4&1 \qquad\scriptsize5&1 \qquad\scriptsize7&1\qquad\scriptsize6\\ \hline
X  Y\quad\scriptsize{11}&0 \qquad\scriptsize12&0  \qquad\scriptsize13&1 \qquad\scriptsize15&0\qquad\scriptsize14\\ \hline
X \overline Y\quad\scriptsize{10}&1\qquad\scriptsize8&1\qquad\scriptsize9&1\qquad\scriptsize11&0\qquad\scriptsize10\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

- quad$[0,1,4,5] = \overline X\overline Z$
- quad$[4,5,7,6] = \overline XY$
- pair$[8,9] = X\overline Y\overline Z$
- pair$[15,11]  = XZW$.

So $F = \overline X\overline Z + \overline XY + X\overline Y\overline Z + XZW$

---

**Solution given in the book :-**

- quad$[8,9,1,0]  = \overline Y\overline Z$
- quad$[4,5,7,6]  = \overline XY$
- pair$[15,11] =  XZW$.

Hence $F = \overline Y\overline Z + XZW + \overline XY$.

Why did I get a different solution than given in the book ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific syntax, but guess that it should be `pair[8,9]` (not `quad[8, 9]`)

Comment: @Marco13 Yes it was my mistake, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some redundancy in there. Your terms, visually, correspond to these blocks:

[image: KV01a]

Note that 4 and 5 are covered with two blocks. Therefore, you had to cover 8 and 9 with an additional block.

The solution from the book uses these blocks:

[image: KV01b]

(Remember that the blocks can "wrap around" the border). This solution is really minimal and has no redundancies, as it covers the $1$s with the smallest number of blocks.

<sub>Extended in response to the comments:</sub>

The rules that must be followed when creating the groups are summarized at the (German version of) the [Wikipedia site about Karnaugh-Veitch-Diagrams](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh-Veitch-Diagramm#Regeln_f%C3%BCr_die_Gruppenbildung). I'll add the translations here, split into two parts: The "basic" rules are these:

- Neighboring/adjacent fields that contain a $1$ are summarized into groups
- A group may not contain a field that does not contain a $1$
- All $1$s must be contained in groups
- The groups may only have sizes that are powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...)
- The groups must be rectangular blocks
- The groups may wrap around the borders

The rules that are important in order to really find the *minimal* solution are:

- The groups must be as large as possible
- There must be as few groups as possible
- The groups may overlap
- Two groups may not contain the exact same set of $1$s
- No group may be fully contained in another group

Comment: If I don't already know the solution, how would I know if my solution is minimal or not ?

Comment: @user45914123 I added two sentences about this: The goal is to cover the $1$s with the fewest number of blocks. To achieve this, you try to make the blocks as large as possible. The solution from the book is optimal, because you cannot make the blocks any larger, all the $1$s are covered, and you cannot cover them with fewer than 3 blocks.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about "fewest number of blocks" constraint. Is there an algorithm to make most optimal K-map ? I see [websites](http://www.32x8.com/) that can calculate K-maps, I don't think they use brute force to calculate the most optimal K-map. What do you think ?

Comment: @user45914123 I'm not aware of a particular "algorithm" that may be applied to KV diagrams. In some way, this would not make sense: The KV diagrams are *intended* to be a simple way of minimizing the function *manually*, by exploiting the human ability to spot patterns (namely, "groups of $1$s"). A real *algorithm* is given, for example, by the [Quine-McCluskey method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), which is equivalent to a KV diagram, but rather *intended* to be implemented as an algorithm in a computer program. (BTW: Added some words about minimization)

Comment: Not clear what you mean with "the groups may not overlap."

Comment: @FabioSomenzi That was the case in the first image in the answer: The red group covers (0,1,4,5). The green group covers (4,5,6,7). So they overlap, because (4,5) are contained in both groups.

Comment: Taken as a general guideline it is misleading, though.  The problem is not the overlap, but the redundancy.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Admittedly, I used "overlap" and "redundancy" synonymously, and when it's boiled down to the terms, they probably are the same. Or can you imagine an overlap that does *not* cause redundancy? (Or vice versa: A redundancy that is not caused by an overlap?)

Comment: Redundancy occurs when either a term can be removed from a cover or a literal can be removed from a term without changing the represented function.  $XY + YZ$ has overlap but no redundancy and is optimal; $XY + \overline{Y}Z + XZ$ has both overlap and redundancy.  Finally, $XY\overline{Z} + YZ$ has no overlap, but it has redundancy.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Well, that's embarassing: It was just a copy+paste translation error :-( Wikipedia says "The groups **may** overlap". I fixed this. Sorry for the mess, and thanks for pointing this out!